# Passing Arrow and Tab keys to Delphi Form in a DLL

Tags: delphi

When a Delphi Form is declared and instantiated inside a DLL and the DLL loaded by the host application, Arrow and Tab keys are not passed across the Host/DLL boundary. This means that TEdit boxes and TMemo controls that may be used on the form will not respond to these key strokes. Is there anyway to ensure that these key strokes are passed from the main application form to the form in the dll? Note there may be multiple DLLs, each containing a form. KeyPreview makes no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forms in DLL's miss this support, as well as support of menu shortcuts (actions). You can write some code to simulate this behaviour.

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// If you display a form from inside a DLL/COM server, you will miss
// the automatic navigation between the controls with the "TAB" key.
// The "KeyPreview" property of the form has to be set to "True".
procedure TForm1.FormKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
var
  bShift: Boolean;
begin
  // Check for tab key and switch focus to next or previous control.
  // Handle this in the KeyPress event, to avoid a messagebeep.
  if (Ord(Key) = VK_TAB) then
  begin
    bShift := Hi(GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT)) <> 0;
    SelectNext(ActiveControl, not(bShift), True);
    Key := #0; // mark as handled
  end;
end;
```

Comment: what about arrow keys and other navigation keys?

Comment: @David Heffernan - The arrow keys should work, when they are used inside a control, though they are normally not used for navigation between controls. The shortcuts of actions and menus can be implemented in a similar way, i can provide a link if somebody would like an example.

Comment: arrows are often used for nav between controls. Surely single VCL is best.

Comment: Arrow keys can be used for navigation, but then you have to write code yourself (it's not the Windows standard behaviour). The same code you wrote to catch the arrow key, should work in the dll.

Comment: No, arrows are very standard. The VCL implements arrow key nav.

Comment: @David Heffernan - I'm not sure what you mean, when i make a form in Delphi 2010, i cannot navigate between controls with the arrow keys. As for the single VCL, this is probably the easiest solution, but sometimes you cannot do this, because you are using COM or the caller is not a Delphi application.

Comment: Try adding a bunch of radio buttons to a form and use the arrow keys to nav between them

Comment: Well i see, it depends on the control, if it uses the arrow key for itself or if it is used for navigation. It should be possible to get the arrow key strokes in the KeyUp event.

Comment: The big problem with this approach is that you are forcing the work onto every single plug-in author. A good plug-in framework should not require that.

Comment: True, but what if you don't have any choice? A package can only be used, if the host application is written in Delphi as well. Other languages and COM are left out.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3815/discussion-between-martinstoeckli-and-david-heffernan)

Comment: The way out is to provide a framework for the plug-ins to create GUI but arrange that the GUI creation is executed in the host app and so picks up the VCL of the host. More work to be sure.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, looks like a nontrivial problem. I shall investigate the possible solution suggested and will return with an answer if its works or not on the arrows, particularly with tedit and tmemo controls which is my biggest problem. If that all fails then its packages.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at this question, and your previous one, I would say that your basic problem is that you are not using runtime packages.

If you were using runtime packages then you would have a single instance of the VCL and module boundaries would not matter.

Without runtime packages you have separate VCL instances. For the VCL form navigation to work correctly you need each control to be recognised as a VCL control. This is not possible when you have multiple VCL instances.

Comment: This is something I did consider and may consider again. My only concern is that packages have to be recompiled if we upgrade to a new Delphi version.